# Use Animate scene in existing website

Tags: javascript, animate-cc

I have created an animation in Adobe Animate CC, which I want to use on an existing website.

My folder structure is:

```
- root/
  - src/
    - html.index
    - generated/
      - symbol/
        - symbol.js
        - images/
          - image.jpg
```

The content of the symbol/ folder is generated by publishing my Animate CC scene.

In html.index I load symbol.js, so that I can use the Animate CC scene, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>main</title>

    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
    <script src="generated/symbol/symbol.js"></script>
```

I can then create the symbol scene using createjs:

```
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
symbol = new lib.Symbol();
stage.addChild(symbol);
```

**The Problem**

This doesn't work since symbol.js links relatively to image.jpg. When I open html.index the browser looks for "images/image.jpg" instead of "src/generated/symbol/images/image.jpg".

How can I use a scene published from Animate CC on an existing website? Note that I can't change symbol.js since it is generated by Animate and changes whenever the graphics artists updates the scene and republishes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy everything in src/generated/symbol into the root directory of your existing web site, and load your script as "symbol.js" instead of "generated/symbol/symbol.js". The src/generated/symbol directory structure is just a kind of scaffolding for your code while you are developing it. It's not intended to dictate to you what the final structure of your web site needs to be.

Comment: It would unfortunately be quite inconvenient if I couldn't launch the website from inside our IDE (WebStorm), but had to run a script before testing changes to the site.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Publish Seetings", untick the box "Overwrite HTML file on publish". Then go and edit the HTML file created by Animate CC with the correct file structure.